# Errors not rendering when form being submitted via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a multi-model form submission that appends all model errors into a single hash called @errors.  When submitting using a normal HTML post the errors correctly render in my view:

**new.html.erb**

```
<div id="error_explanation">
<% if @errors && @errors.any? %>
   <% @errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
   <h3><%= msg %></h3>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

However when submitting using AJAX nothing renders, I can verify that the hash contains values when outputting to the log.

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @errors && @errors.any? %>
   <% @errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><%= logger.info msg %><% end %> // Works!!
   $('#error_explanation').html('<% @errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><%= msg %><% end %>'); // Doesn't Work
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the text:

```
$('#error_explanation').html('<%= escape_javascript @errors.full_messages.join("<br/>") %>');
```

If there is still a bug, provide the resulting js.

Comment: This works except the <br /> isn't being rendered but is showing up as text.  Example: errorMessage1<br />errorMessage2<br />

Answer (score 1):

I think `<% @errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><%= msg %><% end %>` should return an array.

You could use something like

```
<% @errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
   $('#error_explanation').append(msg);
<% end %>
```